# Showing progress bar on top of page while Winjs.ui.listview is loading

Tags: windows-8, winjs

How to show the indeterminate progress bar on top of the page while Winjs.UI.ListView fetching the data. Is there any built in feature to show the progress in Winjs?

Comment: The list view is supposed to show a spinner while the promise that is getting data returned from a custom data source is still in progress.  However, if you don't have a custom data source, you will need to show your Dow. Like Daniel mentions below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the method where you fetch your daya is `getData()`.

```
function getData(){
var progress = document.createElement("progress");
document.getElementById("someDiv").appendChild(progress); //we have created and appended an undetermined progress bar.
//do the data fetching, and, when it's over and ítems have been asigned to the ListView remove the progress element from the div.
}
```

Otherwise, in HTML:

```
<progress></progress>
```

Comment: There's also a good MSDN tutorial explaning how progress controls work in WinJS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465487.aspx